# Fail to update Firebase security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a database and got an email that my rules are not secure.
this is what i have now:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

i wanted to change it to something like in the example in the site, so a user can read\write only to his record, but this doesn't work. i get denied.

what am i doing wrong?

how do i know if my key is $uid or $user_id?

the database structure is like:

```
root
  --uid
    -- all the data
```

Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }

  }
}
```

sample of my data:

[image: sample of my data]

[image: Playground]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that anyone of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that code, it's hard to say why the rules don't work for you.

Comment: Hi Frank,the question refer only to the Firebase Rules Playground. not to my code itself. I added a sample of my data. please let me know if more information is needed. thanks

Comment: In that case, please add a screenshot of the rules playground with all relevant information showing. Without seeing what doesn't work for you, it'll be hard to help.

Comment: these are the rules that I  put in the original message. also attached an image

Answer (score 0):

These rules that you use in the playground screenshot:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }

  }
}
```

In these rules the `$uid` is a variable, meaning that the rules under that node apply to any top-level node. These rules then you allow the user to read/write their own data, when the path (`$uid`) matches their own UID.

But in the same playground screenshow you're trying to read `/uid`, in which case `uid` is just a hard-coded value. Since the `auth.uid` is not the actual UID of your user, the read/write is denied.

With the user that you've set up in the playground screenshot, you can read/write location `/c252019c-c9c3-461e-bb79-e8a346862f08` (the UID of the user).